# Cannot update the marker on Kivy-Mapview Python

Tags: python, kivy, gps

Hello guys. Hope you are all doing well.

I have just started using Kivy Mapview on Python and done some examples. Now, I am trying to create a dynamic marker which is able to move/reposition itself in every 0.5 seconds. I am conducting a project, and at the end of it I need to provide a real-time GPS tracking. That is the reason why I am trying to create a  dynamic marker. Here is what I have tried:

**.py file:**

```
from kivy.garden.mapview import MapView, MapMarker
from kivy.app import App
import time

class MapViewApp(App):
    def build(self):
        while True:
            increment = 0.0001
            mapview = MapView(zoom=19, lat=40.219867, lon=28.964641)
        
            marker_1 = MapMarker(lon=28.964641 + increment, lat=40.219867 + increment, source="circle_PNG36.png")
            mapview.add_marker(marker_1)
            increment = increment + 0.01
            mapview.remove_marker(marker1)
            time.sleep(0.5)
        
MapViewApp().run()
```

**.kv file:**

```
#:import MapView kivy.garden.mapview.MapView

MapView:
    MapMarkerPopup:
    lat: self.lat
    lon: self.lon
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several problems with your code, but the main issue is that your `MapViewApp` will never run, because there is an infinite loop in your `build()` method. Since the `build()` method never returns, the `runTouchApp()` method never gets executed.

On a related note, you also do not want to put that infinite loop on the main thread of a `kivy` `App`. The updating of an `App` GUI takes place on the main thread and if some method is hogging the main thread, the GUI will be frozen. Such a loop should be run on a separate thread, with any modifications that it makes to the GUI accomplished with something like `Clock.schedule_once()` to get those GUI modifications back on the main thread.

Comment: You were absolutely right. I looked around a bit and found a code which had similar purposes. Modified it according to what you mentioned at it all worked. Thank you for your heads up, appreciate it!